# jQuery script/functions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a small "game" of sorts I suppose. And I am having trouble with the jquery bit. I have it so when I click the alien it adds 1 to the counter, and that works great! However, I am trying to add a second function that will only work if I have clicked the alien 10 times. When I have 10 aliens, I want to be able to click a button on screen that adds 1 to my spaceship counter. I have done some coding and can't seem to figure out how to get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Alien Clicker!</title>
</head>    
<body>
    <h3><span id="counter">0</span> clicks</h3>
    <h3 id="head2"><span id="factoryc">0</span> spaceships</h3>
    <img id="alien" src="alien.png">
    <img id="whirl" src="whirl.png" style="width:25em; height:25em;">
    <img id="center" src="http://megahdwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Plain-Url-Http-Geprek-             Com-Downlod-Cool-954012-1024x576.jpg">
    <button id="spaceship"></button>
</body>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#alien').click(function() {
       incrementCounter();
    });
});

function incrementCounter() {
    var previousCounter = parseInt($("#counter").text());
    previousCounter = isNaN(previousCounter) ? 0: ++previousCounter;

    $("#counter").text(previousCounter);
}

function resetCounter() {
    $("#counter").text(0);
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#spaceship').click(function() {
       incrementCounter1();
    });
});

if (#counter > 10) {
    function incrementCounter1() {
    var previousCounter1 = parseInt($("#spaceshipc").text());
    previousCounter1 = isNaN(previousCounter1) ? 0: ++previousCounter1;

    $("#spaceshipc").text(previousCounter1);
    });
}); 
  </script> 
</html>
```

There's my code, it's probably completely wrong haha. I would really appreciate if I could get some help on this.

Oh and one more question, I am looking for a college that offers HTML/CSS/Jquery or javascript as classes I can take. Particularly i'm looking for one in Florida since I live here. If anyone has any idea of a college that offers it I would love answers.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use `isNaN(previousCounter1) ? 0 : previousCounter1 + 1` instead of `++previousConter1` as the second part (although technically it shouldn't matter)

Comment: *" it's probably completely wrong haha. I would really appreciate if I could get some help on this.*'" - that is not how it works. This is a `Q&A` site. You should have a clear problem statement. And this is the wrong place to ask for suggestion regarding tools or tutorials (*You might find help in chat though*) Voting to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some issues with your JS to begin with: you do not need to wrap your script in various `$(document).read(function(){...}` — and you can also declare all your JS functions in the same code block. To increase the spaceship whenever you have 10 aliens, simply use the `%` operator, i.e.:

```
if(previousCounter % 10 === 0) {
    $("#factoryc").text(previousCounter/10);
}
```

See the full code below, also ported to a functional fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/bqLn5hon/

```
$(function() {
    $('#alien').click(function() {
        incrementCounter();
    });

    function incrementCounter() {
        var previousCounter = parseInt($("#counter").text());
        previousCounter = isNaN(previousCounter) ? 0: ++previousCounter;

        $("#counter").text(previousCounter);

        if(previousCounter % 10 === 0) {
            $("#factoryc").text(previousCounter/10);
        }
    }

    function resetCounter() {
        $("#counter").text(0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured one function would do I just had no idea how to execute it properly. This helps a ton!

Comment: Thanks for the -1 vote, kind stranger who didn't bother to explain why so.

@DevonGibson Hope that it helped :)